# NodeJS ffmpeg ytdl-core error write EPIPE

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, ffmpeg, ytdl

When trying to merge audio and video from ytdl-core with ffmpeg, it gives me the error: error write EPIPE

```
        res.header("Content-Disposition", `attachment;  filename=video.mp4`)

        let video = ytdl(link, {
            filter: 'videoonly'
        })
        let audio = ytdl(link, {
            filter: 'audioonly',
            highWaterMark: 1 << 25
        });
        const ffmpegProcess = cp.spawn(ffmpeg, [
            '-i', `pipe:3`,
            '-i', `pipe:4`,
            '-map', '1:0',
            '-map', '0:0',
            '-strict', 'experimental',
            '-vcodec', 'libx264',
            '-c:v', 'libx264',
            '-c:a', 'aac',
            '-crf', '27',
            '-preset', 'veryfast',
            '-b:v', '1500k',
            '-b:a', '128k',
            '-movflags', 'faststart',
            '-f', 'mp4',
            '-loglevel', 'error',
            '-',
        ], {
            stdio: [
                'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe',
            ],
        });

    
        video.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[3]);
        audio.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[4]);
        ffmpegProcess.stdio[1].pipe(res);
```

I've tried executing the code with a file output and without "ffmpegProcess.stdio[1].pipe(res);" and it works. But I need that line of code for chrome extension purposes. I've also tried moving around "-movflag" tag and when its accompained with "frag_keyframe" it works but with a wrong video duration.